# Javascript error object required

Tags: javascript, web

I'm helping to debug a website and sometimes i get this error : 
Object required on CWS.js line 45 character 3

```
// Track cursor position
var CWS_curPosX, CWS_curPosY;
document.onmousemove = CWS_MouseMove;

function CWS_MouseMove(evt)
{

if(window.Event)
{
    if(evt && evt.pageX)
    {
        CWS_curPosX = evt.pageX;
        CWS_curPosY = evt.pageY; 
    }
}
else
{
    CWS_curPosX = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft; // line 45
    CWS_curPosY = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop;
}
```

I have no idea to solve this...
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a couple of crucial isues with your code, primarily your use of `window.Event` - this `if(...)` condition will always evaluate false, as no browser supports this property on the `window` object. In actual fact the property has a lower case `e` in IE.

So this construct is often used, and looks similar to yours:

```
function someEventHandler(evt){
   if(window.event){ // Note lower case 'e' in 'event'
       // browser is IE, read properties of the event from window.event
   }
   else{
       // browser is probably some flavour of Mozilla, use the passed-in 'evt' 
       // parameter to read properties of the event
   }
}
```

Read this link ([event object in different browsers](http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/event.shtml)) for more info.

This cross-browser difference is one of many reasons many people tend to use a framework such as jQuery which simplifies this event-handling code into one unified method of reading properties of the event.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, i try it now and i wait the tester's feedback.

Comment: A much simpler way is `event = event || window.event`

Answer (score 0):

replace event to evt in 2 lines
CWS_curPosX = evt.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft;
CWS_curPosY = evt.clientY + document.body.scrollTop;

Comment: In case of the first comment doesn't work i will try your response, thank you for your quick response too!!!